# END of MIB when calling pass_persist script SNMP

Tags: python, snmp

I've to implement something like a monitoring for specific value returned by a script on the server. I've done the script, in python... now I've tried to link it to SNMP via pass_persist:

`pass_persist .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255 /root/isnmp/myscript.py`

when I call

`snmpwalk -On -c public -v 1 localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255`

I got

`End of MIB.`

Answer (score 0):

If `.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255` is the last OID, then End of MIB is something expected for such a WALK operation.

If you want to in fact query `.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255`, you should use GET operation (snmpget), or WALK from another OID, such as `.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but stick on the same error :( 
snmpget -On -c public -v 1 localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255
Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255

Comment: "(noSuchName)" is a completely different error. Did you try to debug following this page? http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I'm able to get the value, I'm using "extend" method. Know I've one more problem that is how to translate something like 'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."mycustom"' to a standard OID to be queried by Zabbix... I think I can't :)

Comment: That last bit sounds like a new question.