# SNMP pass_persist does not seem to execute

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, snmp

While the question [END of MIB when calling pass_persist script SNMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207823/end-of-mib-when-calling-pass-persist-script-snmp#) is close to what I am looking for the answer is clear and not quite my problem(I think).

pass_persist gives no output on my walk.

I am using pip module https://pypi.org/project/snmp-passpersist/ and testing the example with result:

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.1.### .1.3.6.1.3`

`SNMPv2-SMI::experimental = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)`

My permissions are a+x and the file is in /etc/snmp so my snmpd.conf reads as

```
agentAddress udp:161

createUser authOnlyUser  MD5 "authonlyuser"
createUser authPrivUser  SHA "authprivuser"  DES
createUser internalUser  MD5 "internaluser"

view   enterprise   included   .1.3.6.1.3

rocommunity  public default -V enterprise

pass_persist .1.3.6.1.3.53.8.0 /etc/snmp/test.py
```

(btw I know 3 is experimental, this will be changed to 4 enterprise)

My assumption is something to do with the daemon because when I run

`python /etc/snmp/test.py`
The code runs and I get expected results

`PING` returns `PONG` and `DUMP` returns

```
{'0.1': {'label': 'This is a label for this integer',
         'type': 'INTEGER',
         'value': '123'},
 '0.2': {'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'A string'},
 '0.3': {'type': 'OCTET', 'value': '01 00 1f 0b 00 0b'}}
```

I am expecting a similar result in my walk something like

```
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.53.8.0.1 = INTEGER: 123
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.53.8.0.2 = STRING: "A string"
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.53.8.0.3 = OCTET: 01 00 1f 0b 00 0b
```

instead of
`SNMPv2-SMI::experimental = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)`

I have looked in /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages and see the walk is called
and if I put
 `extend .1.3.6.1.3.53.9.0 /bin/echo hello` at the end of snmpd.conf (after the pass_persist)
I get expected output

```
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.53.9.0.1.0 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.53.9.0.2.1.2.9.47.98.105.110.47.101.99.104.111 = STRING: "hello"
```

Where are my persistent values? What might I not be understanding of how pass_persist works?

Answer (score 0):

When installing the pass_persist module I needed to use sudo.
`sudo pip install snmp_passpersist`